# Will Retrofit handle this Signature method "HMAC-SHA256" using SigningInterceptor in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, signpost

Servers Signature method is getting changed from HMAC-SHA1 to HMAC-SHA256 will this get handled by retrofit or should I have to generate and pass it, if so how can this be done?
Currently using https://github.com/pakerfeldt/okhttp-signpost this for signing http request... will this handle HMAC-SHA256